# Store database of web application on local system

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, static-ip-address

I have hosted some web applications (asp.net) as sub-domains on a server. The databases (SQL Server 2008) of those applications are also saved on the same server.

Problem:

One of my customer asked if he can save the database of his application on his local system. I have searched for any information regarding the problem.

Of course, I can save the database on his system, but what IP address should I use to connect my application with that system? Now I am searching for purchasing static IP address for this purpose. Am I on the right direction? Are there any better ways?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The performance would probably be terrible. He would connect to your server in your clould and your server would connect back to his server for the data. I guess you should think of spawining a private cloud for that user, consisting of both database and the application.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Thanks for the reply. How can I create a private cloud for that particular user?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Client has 3 branches and a server in the main branch. So he doubts the security of the database which is stored in our cloud. That is why he wants such a solution. Is there any solution for this scenario?

Comment: Private cloud is an iis plus sql locally at his side.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is that your client wants a "customized" version of your application, and IMHO, that's how I'd tackle it. _Depending on use case_, perhaps, that "local" db can slave off or sync on demand - as use case applies.